# CodeMirror: Entities turned into HTML tag in HTML mode

Tags: codemirror, ui-codemirror

When specifying for example a line of HTML as follows:

`<dt><code>&lt;dl&gt;</code></dt>`

CodeMirror will convert the entities to their tag equivalent i.e.

`<dt><code><dl></code></dt>`

NOTE: This is when CodeMirror is initialised and the first passed as the initial editor content. So it does not happen as you type.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening? Perhaps a config, plugin, or custom function. I have looked over the documentation and does not look like there is anything. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is not caused by CodeMirror but parsing by the browser before the content is sent to the editor :-/